# SSL (HTTPS) support in functional web framework

Tags: spring-web, spring-webflux

How am I supposed to to configure SSL for a Spring Boot Service using the functional web framework?

The configuration via setting server.ssl.* properties does not work (meaning nothing happens at all) and if I am reading the docs right, only server.port and server.address are supported.

As runtime I prefer netty, but I would be fine with tomcat as well.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, using the `server.ssl.*` configuration keys is the right way to go. This is not yet supported as of Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5, but it will be in a future Milestone version (you can follow issue [#9431](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9431) for that).

You could use customizers as a workaround; Spring Boot provides a few of those for Tomcat already (see `TomcatConnectorCustomizer`), but unfortunately not yet for Netty (see [#10418](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10418)).

In the meantime, you can provide your own `ReactiveWebServerFactory` bean and manually set up your Netty server to do that.

Comment: the OP is asking why a feature is not currently working. I'm giving a link to the issue that will make that support available. There's nothing to add and no code sample to provide, since the answer is: not yet supported. I'd be happy to improve my answer - do you have suggestions?